# Removing all characters after the first 10 characters in a vector (R)

Tags: r, date, data-cleaning

I'm a rookie with R and am looking to remove the timestamp from a `date/time` field from Salesforce data. These dates are in the following format `"2019-09-06T07:44:59.9999997904524"` and I need to remove everything after and including the T, then convert to `mm/dd/yyyy` format. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to parse the date and format as desired

```
format(as.Date("2019-09-06T07:44:59.9999997904524"), "%m/%d/%Y")
#OR
format(lubridate::ymd_hms( "2019-09-06T07:44:59.9999997904524"), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "09/06/2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need a regex solution, capture as a group and then rearrange the backreferences

```
sub("(.{4})-(.{2})-(.{2}).*", "\\2/\\3/\\1", v1)
#[1] "09/06/2019"
```

---

Or using `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
format(anytime(v1), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "09/06/2019"
```

---

or in `base R`

```
format(as.Date(v1), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "2019-09-06T07:44:59.9999997904524"
```